# Wcf method interface as parameter seen as object on clientside

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontract, operationcontract

I am using an interface as input parameter in OperationContract. But when I generate the proxy class at client side, the client method is seen as: GetDat(object value) instead of GetData(IMyObj value)

1. Service Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyObj))]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(IMyObj value);
}
```

2. Service class

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetData(IMyObj value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value.MyValue);
    }

}
```

3. Interface

```
public interface IMyObj
{
    int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

4. Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(IMyObj))]
public class MyObj : IMyObj
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Note: There are a lot of similar questions on stackoverflow regarding to interface parameters and wcf. But they all tell to use the ServiceKnownType attribute and KnownTypeAttribute (Which I did). But it still gives the calling method on the client side an object as parameter type instead of my interface type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other people who are running into the same problem. I've found this answer from Ladislav on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2c52251b-af7f-4529-a2ac-14418ca4b19d/wcf-service-reference-does-not-add-the-interface-definition-of-a-datacontract-of-a-class?forum=wcf

> Hello,
>
> you can't do that. DataContract represents definition of data
>   transfered between client and service. This definition is transformed
>   into XSD which describes format of exchanged XML (serialized data
>   contract object). XML can transfer only data not logic and it doesn't
>   transfer any inormation about data contract implementation = no
>   inheritance and no interface implementation. If you want to use
>   datacontract with interface on the client you have to share that data
>   contract in assembly (not only the interface) and reuse it on the
>   client when service proxy is generated.
>
> Best regards, Ladislav